# Ext.window.MessageBox draggable false, error calling hide method

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

After creating an instance of MessageBox like this

```
var msgBox = Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox',{draggable: false});
```

*-actually draggable false was set through an override to Ext.window.Window, I'm putting it like this to make it easier to reproduce.*

*- also I do prefer the singleton syntax but there are already a ton of instances created like this in the code I'm working on.*

```
   msgBox.alert("I am a bug, try to close me to reproduce");
```

Trying to close this MessabeBox calls the hide method:

```
hide: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.dd.endDrag();
        me.progressBar.reset();
        me.removeCls(me.cfg.cls);
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
```

which throws the following error:

> Cannot read property 'endDrag' of undefined

Am I missing something or this is a bug?

**UPDATE:**

**I'm using ExtJs 4.1.1 (but also happens in Extjs 4.2.1 (fixed on 4.2.2))**

Any ideas or comments ?

Comment: Hm. Are you sure you are using stock Ext.window.MessageBox? I'm looking in the source and it looks totally different from what you have posted here.

Comment: true this was fixed on 4.2.2, thanks for your clarification. This was an issue until 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this error I'm overriding hide method on MessageBox class:

```
        Ext.define('Ext.window.MessageBox', {
            override: 'Ext.window.MessageBox',
            hide : function () {
                /**
                 * this is the default implementation of hide in minus MessageBox the commented line
                 * */
                var me = this;
                //me.dd.endDrag();
                me.progressBar.reset();
                me.removeCls(me.cfg.cls);
                /**
                 * this is the implementation of hide in Ext.Component
                 * avoided callParent() because that would have called the overridden hide method
                */
                me.showOnParentShow = false;
                if (!(me.rendered && !me.isVisible()) && me.fireEvent('beforehide', me) !== false) {
                    me.hidden = true;
                    if (me.rendered) {
                        me.onHide.apply(me, arguments);
                    }
                }
                return me;
            }
        });
```

**Update, this was the original override**

```
Ext.window.Window.override({
    initComponent: function () {
        this.draggable = false;
        this.resizable = false;
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

I'm open to suggestions to avoid this override. Thanks.