# Extjs Window not working after reopen

Tags: extjs

I am getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCls' of null

for the following Scenario

I have created two desktop Icons with Its Window called Masters and Projects. By clicking Masters Icon It opens the master's window , after closing the master window It works fine when reopening it , But In case of  projects window It opens the window for first time only, then I close the project's window,  again I am trying to open It. It does not work until page refresh or reload.

I have used close action: 'hide' and close action: 'destroy'. But I am getting the same error.

```
Ext.override(Ext.Window, {
    closeAction: 'hide'
})
```

Please help me to do this Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you post your code for hide and destroy?

Comment: I had a similar issue, this might give you an idea on how to solve your own issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297256/ext-window-messagebox-draggable-false-error-calling-hide-method

Comment: Also what version of the version are you using? If 4 > 4.2.3 or 5 > 5.1 look into the release notes to see if there is an issue with you version. If you can upgrade version I would try that, if you are tied to that specific version look into the actual source code of the hide / close method and override it as in the question I put above.

Answer (score 1):

If the closeAction is hide, you must make sure that you create the window only once and that you keep a reference to the created window. Then you only call `winRef.show()`, not `Ext.create`.